# how do I write out and use EOF in a while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, command, prompt, eof

I want to know how will i keep doing something until the end of the file

I tried while not EOF() : it showed a syntax error when i ran it in command prompt

Comment: Please share the codes you have tried

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. Read(), readlines() will all continue until EOF. `for line in file:` should do the same.. Please add more information about the task you are trying to achieve and what you are using to achieve it. Markdown help can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

while True:

```
    try:
        
        line = file.readline().strip()

        if not line:
            break

         print(line)
    except EOFError:
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).